# Ajax and json returning undefined as variable values

Tags: ajax, json, django, asynchronous

I am doing some testing with ajax to use it in a web page. This code checks is username isnt already registered , but the variables json returns are undefined when I try to show them , any idea why ?.
Here's the code:

```
  $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth_validate/",
           data: {'username': $('#id_nombre').val(), 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val() },
           dataType: "text",
           success: function(response) {
                  var response = $.parseJSON( response );
                  if (response.success){
                      return true;
                  }
                  else{
                      alert(response.error + " " + response.users);
                  }
            },
            error: function(rs, e) {
                   console.log(rs.responseText + "error");
            }
      });
    return false;
})
```

And this is the views.py

```
def auth_validate(request):
    error = ''
    success = False
    users = Users.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('id_nombre', None)
        if not username:
            error = _('Please enter username')
        elif Users.objects.filter(username__exact=username).exists():
            error = _('Sorry this username is already taken')
        else:
            success = True

    ajax_vars = {'success': success, 'error': error, 'users': users}
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(list((ajax_vars))),
                    mimetype='application/json')
```

Comment: why are you wrapping the response in a list ? You  can get rid of the `list` wrap - or you have to access the elements as `response[0].success`, etc.

Comment: Ohh I didnt though that , but using the [0] doesnt work either. I listed them because if not I would get the " is not JSON serializable" error

Comment: You can always do `console.log(response)` on the callback to see what the response structure is. Also, you should not be using `simplejson` any more (deprecated) - `import json` and dump from that module

Comment: So , instead of using list , how can I do to avoid the "is not JSON serializable" error ?

Comment: You can use the `DjangoJSONEncoder` to encode. `json` takes a class argument, which accepts an encoder class argument